# Can Wheel of Sun and Moon go into graveyard from play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Wheel of Sun and Moon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146740) is destroyed – for instance by a disenchant – does it go into the graveyard, or at the bottom of your library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you'd often put [Wheel of Sun and Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wheel%20of%20Sun%20and%20Moon) on your opponent, in which case there's nothing to worry about. It's only affecting cards that'd be put into *their* graveyard, and when it's destroyed it goes to yours.

A more likely similar example is [Rest in Peace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rest%20in%20Peace), which says "If a card or token would be put into a graveyard from anywhere, exile it instead." The Gatherer rulings mention exactly this scenario:

> If Rest in Peace is destroyed by a spell, Rest in Peace will be exiled and then the spell will be put into its owner's graveyard.

That said, Wheel of Sun and Moon behaves in the same way.  If for some reason you use it on yourself, and then destroy it, it will go to the bottom of your library.

Wheel of Sun and Moon creates a replacement effect, which applies as long as it's on the battlefield. When it would be destroyed (i.e. moved to the graveyard) it is still on the battlefield, so the replacement effect changes that to putting it on the bottom of your library.

It's only once it's left the battlefield that the replacement effect goes away, but by that time the effect has already been applied. Note that this means that, if you destroyed it with Disenchant, the Disenchant *will* go to your graveyard, because when you finish resolving the spell and move it from the stack to your graveyard, Wheel of Sun and Moon is now gone.

Comment: +1 but I am not sure I agree with your first sentence. I would keep this on my sideboard and play it on myself when trying to counter mill decks.

Comment: @ColinD I did say "likely" not "always" or even "generally" - from what I've seen, decks that need their graveyards (flashback, reanimator, etc) are a lot more common than mill decks. But perhaps the OP's metagame is a bit different.

Comment: WoSaM is used for more than just graveyard hate or mill protection; I've seen it used to interesting effect for combos, as well. (I mostly play EDH, though.) As a trivial example, WoSaM enchanting self, plus Doubling Season in play, leads to infinite use of Jace, Architect of Thought's final ability.

Comment: Okay, I'll change it to "often" and avoid unnecessary debate about what to use it for.

Comment: @BrianS, can you explain the Jace combo? How does that lead to multiple uses of his final ability?

Comment: @GendoIkari I think the idea is that you activate his final ability when he has exactly 8 loyalty, put it on the stack, SBAs happen and he tries to go to your graveyard, goes to the bottom of your library instead. Then when the ability resolves, you search for him in your library, cast him for free, and Doubling Season brings him into play with 8 counters instead of 4.

Comment: @Jefromi, And, of course, you also cast something from each opponent's library, so the loop accomplishes something, too ;)